# UITableView reset ContentOffset when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView as Subview in a UIViewController. When the user presses the UITextfield under the tableView, I set the contentOffset of the tableView when the keyboard appears. If I scroll like 1 point (upwards/ downwards) the table view resets it's contentOffset to it's default value. I'm sure that I'm not reseting the contentOffset to Zero anywhere in my code. Why is that happening?
Here is how i'm setting the ContentOffset:

```
CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, keyboardEndFrame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you also setting the bottom padding of the `UITableView` to be as high as the keyboard? Either that, or resizing the `UITableView` so that it ends where the keyboard starts... If you don't, the table view will technically be scrolled passed it's bottom, so scrolling it with your finger will cause it to reset the scroll position...

Comment: @jjv360 Nope i'm not doing that. how can i add bottom padding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a padding to a UITableView so that it's content can be scrolled above the keyboard, you can do something like this:

```
-(void) keyboardMoved:(NSNotification*)notify {

    // Get values
    CGRect endFrame;
    [[[notify userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&endFrame];
    endFrame = [self.view convertRect:endFrame fromView:nil];

    // Add padding
    int inset = self.view.bounds.size.height - endFrame.origin.y;
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, inset < 0 ? 0 : inset, 0);
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I would like to add that if there is any tabBar that is hidden when the ViewController appears, we should add 44 to the inset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you does not resize content size, basically for example:

you have uiTableView, with its size 320 * 400 and the same content size, you shows keyboard and set content offset, but not change content size(I mean you set unposible offset), than you begin scroll, and yours table scrolls to it posible offset value, in this case you need to increase content size. But for tableView better is to add contentInset with calculated bottom inset.